# How to HTML entity encode / decode in ballerina?

Tags: html-encode, ballerina

Currently I'm having a requirement of HTML entity encode / decode using [Ballerina](https://ballerina.io/)  language. However I couldn't find any references for that.

If I have a string as following,

```html
https&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;spdx.org&#x2f;licenses&#x2f;Apache-2.0.html
```

Expected result would be,

```
https://spdx.org/licenses/Apache-2.0.html
```

You can refer to the following screenshot where I have done the same thing using an online tool : https://mothereff.in/html-entities

[image: html entity encode / decode sample]

How can we achieve the above?

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct Ballerina module that provides this functionality. But it can be done using the Java interoperability feature in the Ballerina language.

The StringEscapeUtils class of [Apache common-text](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text) library can be used for this.

Steps:

1. Create a new Ballerina project using `bal new <project name>` command.
2. Generate Ballerina bindings for StringEscapeUtils using below command.

`bal bindgen -mvn org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.9 org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils`

3. Build the project using `bal build` command.
4. Write the Ballerina code for encode and decode.

```
import ballerina/io;
import htmlTest.org.apache.commons.text as text;

public function main() {
    string? decodedText = text:StringEscapeUtils_unescapeHtml3("https&#x3a;&#x2f;&#x2f;spdx.org&#x2f;licenses&#x2f;Apache-2.0.html");
    if decodedText is string {
        io:println(decodedText); //Output : https://spdx.org/licenses/Apache-2.0.html
    } else {
        io:println("Error occured during conversion");
    }
}
```

For more details refer to the [Java interoperability guide](https://ballerina.io/learn/call-java-code-from-ballerina/) on Ballerina.